# Почему неправильный вывод?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка у меня выводит

> Herlo world

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String str=new String("Herlo world");
         
        str.replace('r','l').trim().contains("Aa");
        str.substring(0,2);
          
        System.out.println(str);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: почитай про неизменяемость строк в java

Comment: а какого результата вы ожидаете?

Comment: И про то, что именно делает replace и как им пользоваться.

Comment: Вам @timur правильно написал. Эти методы (как и любые другие для строк) не меняют сами строки, а создают новую обработанную строку и возвращают ссылку на неё. Вам нужно сохранить куда-то эту ссылку, хоть в ту же переменную.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer("Herlo world");
      str.replace(2,2,"l");

        System.out.println(str.replace(2,2,"l").substring(0,6).concat("Aa"))

Comment: Вот как я сделала

Comment: но почему то выводиться HellrlAa

Comment: я разобралась, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

String.substring возвращает измененную строку (на самом деле возвращает объект который ссылается на нужный кусок строки, так как строки в java неизменяемые), по этому нужно что-то вроде этого писать:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str=new String("Herlo world");

        String ret = str.replace('r','l').trim();//.contains("Aa");
        ret = str.substring(0,2);

        System.out.println(ret);
    }
}
```

При этом проверку на наличие символов нужно ставить в блоке ветвления, так как по сути в этом тексте она не играет ни какой роли, а вот субстринг можно присоединить к существующей цепочке изменения строки.